# how to write local unit test for retrofit api call in android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am new to local unit test in android.
I was using retrofit 2.0 for making network call. I have require to write local unit test case. But i am not getting idea, how to write unit test case for retrofit call API. Please can any one give any idea about retrofit api local unit test with or without mockito.

Comment: this may be pedantic, but unit tests do not include network, or database, or sdk testing. unit tests should be just data of your code.
if you're going to do network tests, then those are called integration tests.

in other words, if you're going to do actual unit tests of retrofit code, you need to provide the expected response, and at that point you're just testing the request parsing, and response parsing.

if you want to test the network flow, you'll end up with an integration test

Comment: Hi i am looking for retrofit api unit test with mocking request and response.